# iText Pdf Header Removal for particular page

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I'm generating a PDF with iText, in that I'm displaying a header and footer.
Now i want to remove header for a particular page.

For eg: If I'm generating a 50 pages pdf, for the final 50th I don't want to show header,
how could this be achieved?

Here's my code where I'm generating footer (header part removed).

```
public class HeaderAndFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper {

public void onEndPage (PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    Rectangle rect = writer.getBoxSize("art");
    switch(writer.getPageNumber() % 2) {
    case 0:

    case 1:
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
                Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(String.format("%d", writer.getPageNumber())),
                300f, 62f, 0);
        break;
    }

}
```

}

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us some code, particularly the part where you create/add the header.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 2-pass approach:

- 1st pass : generate the PDF file without header
- 2nd pass : stamp the header on all but the last page

Have a look at this example taken from the iText book. You'll just have to adapt the second pass by only going through the N-1 first pages:

```
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages() - 1;
```

instead of

```
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also in need to do the same. I want to share how I resolved this issue.

The Idea is, for the automatic generation of header footer, we set page event on *PDFWriter* like:

```
HeaderAndFooter event= new HeaderAndFooter(); //HeaderAndFooter is the implementation of PdfPageEventHelper class
writer.setPageEvent(event);// writer is the instance of PDFWriter
```

So, before the content of the last page, We can remove the event:

```
 event=null;
 writer.setPageEvent(event);
```

It works for me without any error or exception.